# Can the DDD debugger be run with pdb instead of pydb?

Tags: ubuntu, pdb, ddd-debugger

I am trying to set up the DDD debugger on Ubuntu to debug python3 programs. However, as the documentation of ddd suggests, for python programs it uses pydb. Invoking ddd --pydb produces an error on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04), since pydb is not installed and not installable - it seems to have been depreciated some time ago.

So I was wondering if it is possible to use DDD with the newer PDB debugger (or any python3-conform python debugger, for that matter).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With greatly reduced capability, it's possible to use pdb 3.10 with ddd 3.3.12. Add a link in your /bin directory pydb -> /bin/pdb3.10, and with the pydb switch on in ddd, the pdb debugger will show up in the debugger window, able to run and enter commands.  The source will not show up in the source window -- it needs an explicit File/Open Source from the ddd menu. Nothing function in the source windows like setting breakpoints or showing the execution point -- only useful for adding the line numbers so your pdb codmmand can use the line number for a break.  The ddd command window will not be functional, nor will the function keys for "next" etc.